# Dynamically assign a value through loop - Android - Programmatically by java

Tags: java, android, loops, variables, dynamic

Here is the list of custom-made rounded images. need to dynamically assign a value through the loop.

```
            RoundedImageView img23 = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar23);
            img23.setImageResource(R.mipmap.avatars_male_28);

            RoundedImageView img24 = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar24);
            img24.setImageResource(R.mipmap.avatars_male_29);

            RoundedImageView img25 = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar25);
            img25.setImageResource(R.mipmap.avatars_male_30);

            for (i = 1;i>25; i++){
                j=(String) i;

                //need a loop that dynamically sets img**2** (any number)
                img<j>.setImageResource(R.mipmap.avatars_male_30);
            }
```

Comment: add the Images to a list or Array?

Comment: create a list `List<RoundedImageView>` and then iterate your list. easy,fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you can do by making imageview type model and then extract imageview from model and use your drawables into imageview Like this...

```
    //You can make ImageViewModel type class there you save your image view
     class ImageViewModel {

        public ImageView getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public void setImage(ImageView image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        ImageView image;

    }
    ArrayList<ImageViewModel> images = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<>();
    drawables.add(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    drawables.add(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    drawables.add(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);



    //set you imageview in model class and add into the arraylist of modelclass type
    ImageViewModel model = new ImageViewModel();
    model.setImage(imageviews);
    images.add(model);




   // Then you can set this as
    for(int i = 0; i<drawables.size(); i++){

         model.getImage().setImageResource(drawables.get(i));
    }
```

Hence You can set your images into Imageview dynamically

This worked for me may be for you also

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating 
`RoundedImageView img1, RoundedImageView img2, RoundedImageView img3` ...

just create an ArrayList of RoundImageView:

```
ArrayList<RoundedImageView> list = new ArrayList<RoundedImageView>();
list.add((RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar1));
list.add((RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar2));
list.add((RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar3));
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all this boilerplate code use butterknife library http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/